# Cakephp upgrade from 1.3 to 2.3 shell not upgrading properly?

Tags: cakephp

I upgraded my app using upgrade shell. The ouput was normal. Though after deleting the cake folder (the last step of the upgrade instructions at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/upgrade-shell.html) I got the following errors:

```
Warning: include(cake\bootstrap.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\wamp\projects\myproject\app\webroot\index.php on line 76

( ! ) Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'cake\bootstrap.php' for inclusion (include_path='D:\wamp\projects\myproject;D:\wamp\projects\myproject\app\;.;C:\php\pear') in D:\wamp\projects\myproject\app\webroot\index.php on line 76

( ! ) Fatal error: CakePHP core could not be found. Check the value of CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in APP/webroot/index.php. It should point to the directory containing your \cake core directory and your \vendors root directory. in D:\wamp\projects\myproject\app\webroot\index.php on line 77
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to upgrade your webroot files (index.php and test.php).
Either do that manually be copying the files from the 2.3 app dir - or use my upgrade shell an d run `cake Upgrade.Upgrade webroot`:
https://github.com/dereuromark/upgrade

Comment: Mark, yours upgrade repository works from cake 1.3 to 2.3?

Comment: I clarified in the https://github.com/dereuromark/upgrade/blob/develop/README.md that this is for 2.x to 3.x and https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-upgrade for 1.x to 2.x :)